# Analysis stop: gzip: stdout: No space left on device but has space

Tags: linux, server, gzip, space

I’m performing a rna-seq analysis on Linux remote server and I keep getting this after 2 aligned samples:

```
Gzip: stdout: no space left on device
```

Looking in htop it has 1.71G/92.8G and Swp: 1.84/4.00G so I don’t understand why I don’t have space that I can’t even make a new dir.

Someone know how to resolve this?? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:: using df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         47G     0   47G   0% /dev
tmpfs            47G     0   47G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            47G  2.3G   45G   5% /run
tmpfs            47G     0   47G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3       218G   40G  179G  19% /
/dev/sda2       976M  224M  685M  25% /boot
/dev/sda1       599M  6.9M  592M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/md0        3.7T  3.7T   20K 100% /home
tmpfs           9.3G     0  9.3G   0% /run/user/1003
```

Looks like the home dir its the problem. But its a multiuser server? Do you guys have any tips??

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right device?  It's quite likely that it's using `$TMPDIR` for fast temporary storage, for example.  Look at _all_ the filesystems listed in `df -h`.

Comment: Oh thanks! Look there and apparently its the home dir (pls look at the update in the main question). Since I'm using a mutiuser server, do you know if it has someway the I can redirect the G for my personal user??

Comment: Next most likely is that it's using your working directory - try changing directory to a filesystem where you have more writable space.  After that, perhaps temporarily setting `HOME` might work, or moving the input files to another location (if it's decompressing into the directory where the sources are).  Without seeing the program that's invoking gzip, that's all just guesswork, though.